# Use MultiThreading to read a file faster

Tags: java

I want to read a file of 500 Mb with the help of 2 threads, so that reading the file will be much faster. Someone please give me some code for the task using core java concepts.

Comment: In most setups, the limiting factor is going to be the speed of the disk read, not the number of threads attempting to perform the read... I'd expect you to be more likely to introduce contention and slow the read down....

Comment: When you read a file sequentially, the OS detects this and reads the file ahead for you. i.e. it has a "thread" trying to read ahead automatically.

Comment: Have you considered memory mapping the file to improve performance?  As forsvarir states the limiting factor is unlikely to be the number of threads.

Comment: The disk controller also reads ahead, and there is likely to be another level of read-ahead in the actual disk itself.

Answer (score 12):

Multi-threading is not likely to make the code faster at all. This because reading a file is an I/O-bound process. You will be limited by the speed of the disk rather than your processor.

Comment: +1: Often the parsing of the file read takes longer than the reading of the file.  This part may benefit from using multiple CPUs. However, the plain reading of the file won't.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to multi-thread the reading, you may benefit from multi-threading the processing of the data.  This can make it look like using multiple threads to read can help, but in reality, using one thread to read and multiple threads to process is often better.

This often takes longer and is CPU bound. Using multiple threads to read files usually helps when you have multiple files on different physical disks (a rare occasion)

Comment: @Lawrey:`usually helps when you have multiple files on different physical disks`.I think it helps for multiple files even on the same disk.Doesn't it?

Comment: +1 on different physical disks. I have two machines with 4 and 8 HDs respectively (unraided) to get more disk speed via threading.

Comment: You can get a margin benefit accessing multiple files on the same filesystem using multiple threads.  The OS can choose which file to read next based on where the files are placed on disk. However, its just as likely to be worse.

Comment: Using independant disks improves performance which you distibute work between them optimally.  However, if you group the disks together e.g. pair you can get an improvement even when accessing one file (or a small number) Its much easier to get an improvement, but it may not be as optimal.

Comment: The stuff I do is very even and distributable. When threaded properly, I can easily get near-linear speedup with a bunch of drives. Getting > 1 GB/s of disk bandwidth over 8 drives is typical. And makes streaming through several TB of data very speedy. :) But here, we're talking an extreme case of HPC and not very representative of most apps.

Answer (score 0):

While you might not be able to speed up the read from disc by using multiple threads to read the file you can speed up the process by not doing processing in the same thread as the read.
This will be dependant on the contents of the file.