# JAVA - Reading and encrypting large number of passwords from text - Any way to speed it up?

Tags: java, performance, api, encryption, passwords

I am trying to read in a large file whose lines are comprised of e-mail:password combinations. I am then encrypting them using Mega.co.nz's API. This works fine, but the encryption process is just too slow to process 100+MB text files in a reasonable amount of time.

I originally made this in Python, but it was way too slow. I figured JAVA would speed it up considerably, but it didn't. It did speed it up a small amount, but not by much.

Would this be a task suited for multi-threading?

Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   private long[] password_aes;
   private String uh = "";
   private static final char[] CA = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();
   private static final int[] IA = new int[256];
   private String fileName = "C://combo_encrypted.txt";



    static {
        Arrays.fill(IA, -1);
        for (int i = 0, iS = CA.length; i < iS; i++)
            IA[CA[i]] = i;
        IA['='] = 0;
    }

   RunnableDemo( String name){
       threadName = name;
   }

   public void run() {


   FileWriter fileWriter;
try {
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    String finalString = "";
    String[] parts = threadName.split(":");
    password_aes = prepare_key_pw(parts[1]);
    uh = stringhash(parts[0], password_aes);
    finalString = (parts[0] + ":" + parts[1] + ":" + uh + "\n");
    System.out.println(finalString);
    bufferedWriter.write(finalString);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

   }



   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }


public static long[] str_to_a32(String string) {
    if (string.length() % 4 != 0) {
        string += new String(new char[4 - string.length() % 4]);
    }
    long[] data = new long[string.length() / 4];

    byte[] part = new byte[8];
    for (int k = 0, i = 0; i < string.length(); i += 4, k++) {
        String sequence = string.substring(i, i + 4);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            baos.write(sequence.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            System.arraycopy(baos.toByteArray(), 0, part, 4, 4);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(part);
            data[k] = bb.getLong();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            data[k] = 0;
        }
    }
    return data;
}

public static String a32_to_str(long[] data) {
    byte[] part = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        bb.putLong(data[i]);
        part = Arrays.copyOfRange(bb.array(), 4, 8);
        bb.clear();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(part);
        while (bais.available() > 0) {
            builder.append((char) bais.read());
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static byte[] aes_cbc_encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key) {
    String iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
    byte[] output = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        output = cipher.doFinal(data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}

public static long[] aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(long[] idata, long[] ikey) {
    try {
        byte[] data = a32_to_str(idata).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        byte[] key = a32_to_str(ikey).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        byte[] encrypt = aes_cbc_encrypt(data, key);

        return str_to_a32(new String(encrypt, "ISO-8859-1"));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new long[0];
}

public static String base64_url_encode(String data) {

    try {
        data = new String(base64_url_encode_byte((data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")),true), "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    data = data.replaceAll("\\+", "-");
    data = data.replaceAll("/", "_");
    data = data.replaceAll("=", "");

    return data;
}

public static String a32_to_base64(long[] a) {
    return base64_url_encode(a32_to_str(a));
}

public static String stringhash(String email, long[] aeskey) {
    long[] s32 = str_to_a32(email);
    long[] h32 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < s32.length; i++) {
        h32[i % 4] ^= s32[i];
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < 0x4000; r++) {
        h32 = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(h32, aeskey);
    }
    long[] h32Part = new long[2];
    h32Part[0] = h32[0];
    h32Part[1] = h32[2];
    return a32_to_base64(h32Part);
}

public static long[] prepare_key(long[] password) {
    long[] pkey = {0x93C467E3, 0x7DB0C7A4, 0xD1BE3F81, 0x0152CB56};
    for (int r = 0; r < 0x10000; r++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < password.length; j += 4) {
            long[] key = {0, 0, 0, 0};
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (i + j < password.length) {
                    key[i] = password[i + j];
                }
            }
            pkey = aes_cbc_encrypt_a32(pkey, key);
        }
    }
    return pkey;}

public static long[] prepare_key_pw(String password) {
    return prepare_key(str_to_a32(password));
}

   public final static byte[] base64_url_encode_byte(byte[] sArr, boolean lineSep){
        // Check special case
        int sLen = sArr != null ? sArr.length : 0;
        if (sLen == 0)
            return new byte[0];

        int eLen = (sLen / 3) * 3;                              // Length of even 24-bits.
        int cCnt = ((sLen - 1) / 3 + 1) << 2;                   // Returned character count
        int dLen = cCnt + (lineSep ? (cCnt - 1) / 76 << 1 : 0); // Length of returned array
        byte[] dArr = new byte[dLen];

        // Encode even 24-bits
        for (int s = 0, d = 0, cc = 0; s < eLen;) {
            // Copy next three bytes into lower 24 bits of int, paying attension to sign.
            int i = (sArr[s++] & 0xff) << 16 | (sArr[s++] & 0xff) << 8 | (sArr[s++] & 0xff);

            // Encode the int into four chars
            dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 18) & 0x3f];
            dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 12) & 0x3f];
            dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 6) & 0x3f];
            dArr[d++] = (byte) CA[i & 0x3f];

            // Add optional line separator
            if (lineSep && ++cc == 19 && d < dLen - 2) {
                dArr[d++] = '\r';
                dArr[d++] = '\n';
                cc = 0;

            }
        }

        // Pad and encode last bits if source isn't an even 24 bits.
        int left = sLen - eLen; // 0 - 2.
        if (left > 0) {
            // Prepare the int
            int i = ((sArr[eLen] & 0xff) << 10) | (left == 2 ? ((sArr[sLen - 1] & 0xff) << 2) : 0);

            // Set last four chars
            dArr[dLen - 4] = (byte) CA[i >> 12];
            dArr[dLen - 3] = (byte) CA[(i >>> 6) & 0x3f];
            dArr[dLen - 2] = left == 2 ? (byte) CA[i & 0x3f] : (byte) '=';
            dArr[dLen - 1] = '=';
        }
        return dArr;
    }

}


public class TestThread {


   final static String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\combo_encrypted.txt";

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {





  File file1 = new File("File1.txt");
  File file2 = new File("File2.txt");
  File file3 = new File("File3.txt");
  File file4 = new File("File4.txt");

  FileInputStream fis1 = null;
  FileInputStream fis2 = null;
  FileInputStream fis3 = null;
  FileInputStream fis4 = null;

  BufferedInputStream bis1 = null;
  BufferedInputStream bis2 = null;
  BufferedInputStream bis3 = null;
  BufferedInputStream bis4 = null;

  DataInputStream dis1 = null;
  DataInputStream dis2 = null;
  DataInputStream dis3 = null;
  DataInputStream dis4 = null;

  fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);    
  fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
  fis3 = new FileInputStream(file3);
  fis4 = new FileInputStream(file4);

  bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(fis1);
  bis2 = new BufferedInputStream(fis2);
  bis3 = new BufferedInputStream(fis3);
  bis4 = new BufferedInputStream(fis4);

  dis1 = new DataInputStream(bis1);
  dis2 = new DataInputStream(bis2);
  dis3 = new DataInputStream(bis3);
  dis4 = new DataInputStream(bis4);

  while ( (dis4.available() != 0) ) {
        String combo1 = dis1.readLine();
        String combo2 = dis2.readLine();
        String combo3 = dis3.readLine();
        String combo4 = dis4.readLine();

        RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo(combo1);
        RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo(combo2);
        RunnableDemo R3 = new RunnableDemo(combo3);
        RunnableDemo R4 = new RunnableDemo(combo4);

        R1.start();
        R2.start();
        R3.start();
        R4.start();
  }

  fis1.close();
  fis2.close();
  fis3.close();
  fis4.close();

  bis1.close();
  bis2.close();
  bis3.close();
  bis4.close();

  dis1.close();
  dis2.close(); 
  dis3.close(); 
  dis4.close(); 

   }   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use MultiThreading to read a file faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632318/use-multithreading-to-read-a-file-faster)

Comment: Have you performed any profiling to determine precisely where the bottleneck is? You should also verify that you are not incurring garbage collection pauses.

Answer (score 0):

What funny things are you doing??? Do you really want to encrypt a file? If so, then do it. A file is a sequence of bytes and that's exactly what `Cipher.update` and `Cipher.doFinal` work with.

Read bytes, encrypt bytes, write bytes. Done. Converting into strings, base64, `long[]`, and whatelse useless stuff just slows it all down.

Maybe you want something else than file encryption, but then you should describe it clearly. You seem to be doing some line-wise processing which may be what's required but I can't make sense of it.

You could speed up the line-wise processing by avoiding conversions from bytes to strings and similar stuff. Also the creating of a new cipher and similar stuff don't speed things up.

> Would this be a task suited for multi-threading?

In case you really need line-wise processing, I guess so. But unless you have dozens of cores, you can gain more by cleaning up the code first.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do not want to encrypt a file. I want to read an e-mail address and password from a line in a text file and create an encrypted string based on those two parsed strings.

Comment: @pelayo I see (I should have read the question title, not only the text!). The encryption algorithm looks a bit strange, in case it's your own invention, ask about its security. +++ *The parts of my answer about avoiding converting between different formats and re-creating of cipher etc. still apply.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the encryption is the culprit, try to use multiple threads to do the encryption stage. You can achieve this by pipelining your program like this:
[image: Pipeline]

This however assumes that the order of the resulting list does not matter. If it does matter you would need some sort of sorting after the encryption stage.

Answer (score 0):

The code is slow, as the code implements some sort of **[Key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)** (**It's slow on purpose**). As it's CPU bound, It will run faster if you can get it to use all your cores.

But don't expect to find a way to really speed it up, without changing the password algorithm used.

Comment: Hi, I was editing the code as you were replying. Thank you for your response. I made it use multiple threads and it now encrypts all of the passwords very rapidly. I split the file into four smaller text files and I have four streams open, one for each file. I am feeding each line of the text files to a worker simultaneously. A task that used to take 30+ minutes now takes roughly one minute. My new code is very sloppy, but it seems to be functioning. The problem I'm having right now is writing the encrypted password to a new text file. I believe I am approaching it incorrectly.